# Is it really an error when I'm getting Traceback (most recent call last) without the word "error"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I get is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "maian.py", line 24 in <module>
from web3 import web3
file "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/web3/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
```

Correct me if I am wrong, but execution of program stops because the `web3` thing (`__init__.py`) doesn't get loaded for some reason? How can I fix this?

What puzzles me again is that I'm not seeing a message at the very end telling me that something is wrong? I should now debug by trying to print some message...if it doesn't get printed then the program really stops while trying to initialize the `web3` module?

Comment: ..the script maian.py then points to other scripts...notably web3...but i don't get it, i need to try print("something") at the end of maian.py now to see if it really fails...

Comment: this is all output ? weird.

Comment: i can take a screenshot if you need to? i know people on here hate screenshots though :)

Comment: If there is nothing more to copy-paste, what should a screenshot show more ?

Comment: well in case someone doesn't believe me lol! it's a complex program by the way..from the university of Singapore or so and to make it more "complex" I installed z3 in "unusual way", I even suspect this module - z3 - may produce some buffer overflow or something that ends thee program...but all I am seeing here is about web3, so it's 99% a web3 module thing only.

Comment: That does not look like a normal traceback should look. It doesn't even look like a truncated traceback. Did you retype this by hand? If you did, please copy-paste the error message from actual interpreter output.

Comment: [Yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52156073/python-module-web3-doesnt-seem-to-load-correctly-yet-i-am-not-seeing-an-error), you posted a very similar but much longer error message from a `web3` import. Did anything change regarding your `web3` install since then?

Comment: A python error should always end with the error type. Dumb idea: did you try scrolling down to see another line?

Comment: @user2357112 yeah I a lot changed...i even reinstalled the whole ubuntu VM I am testing this on, the previous one was on 16.04 with Python 3 <3.6, this is Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: @pydude: I did! Many times...there is nothing at the very end of the "error" message...just to add though: I am not getting any such messages when I try a new version of this module: web3....the message only occurs on an old version, yet I need this version for other reasons.